# Seeking clever ideas \ suggestions to pole mount water timer

Tags: hardware, mount

I would like to mount [the timer](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Orbit-2-Outlet-Hose-Faucet-Timer-56544/205585024) to a pole, which would be staked into the ground.   The timer would sit 10 inches above the ground. I do not have a clear idea what would be a simple effective means to mount the timer to the pole.

If parts were available via Amazon or Home Depot that would be great: links are appreciated.  Looking forward to clever ideas or similar examples of work (photos).

[image]

Comment: Not much to go on here. Are there mounting holes on the back? How important are aesthetics? My first thoughts are a 2x4 with a pointy tip pounded a few feet into the ground, and then use mounting holes to screw this on, or screw a piece of stainless-steel strapping on, or really hacky: zip-tie it on (black UV-resistant ties).

Comment: Since this is a plastic cheapie, I recommend putting it inside a full enclosure, and plumbing highly flexible hoses so the stiffness of the hose is not putting physical strain on the plastic.  I would prefer fastened down hard lines exiting the enclosure, so someone tripping over a hose doesn't yank the controller and crack it.  Also since I note you are asking this question in ***April***, which is when people in freeze country feel safe activating outdoor plumbing...  think about how to drain the water out of all of it without too much work.

Comment: My experience with these timers is that at least with some of them there is an abrupt shut-off of the water leading to water hammer heard in the kitchen. Over time this can damage pipes and fixtures. Maybe newer and better units have a more gradual shut off, but if your doesn't have this , you may want to use one of those water hammer dampeners between this timer valve and the water source.

Answer (score 3):

I have a battery powered timer that is similar to what you have and it looked not so sturdy so I purchased a [hose hanger](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Suncast-Wicker-Deluxe-Hose-Hanger-Java/35505638) like this and drilled 2 holes for the hose to enter and exit. The small storage space keeps the unit dry and out of site. It still looks new after 3 years. The second unit on the back side of the barn failed in less than 2 years (not protected). Now both have these hose hangers that look nice and the controllers are protected and the grand kids don't play with them.

Answer (score 1):

I like Ed's suggestion as it offers some protection. In my experience, "waterproof" electronic gizmos don't tend to retain that quality after extended use.

My first idea was to use a [faucet on a post](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Yard-Butler-Hose-Bib-Extender-TLYBHBE06/206041745?cm_mmc=SEM%7CTHD%7CG%7C0%7CG-Pro-Services&gclid=Cj0KEQjwrYbIBRCgnY-OluOk89EBEiQAZER58o8R19lpe6v9gXwnP0CMm4yuedJyn_MBiF-kweWvrA0aAsPv8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds) as your mounting hardware:

[image]

You could then mount the timer directly to that, as shown in the [product photos](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Orbit-2-Outlet-Hose-Faucet-Timer-56544/205585024):

[image]

*Home Depot links for reference only.*

Comment: I neglected to mention that the reason for not mounting the timer directly to the hose bib is because I fear that the timer's weight may weaken the aged pipes.  Your clever suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the mounting, if the back of the timer is flat, using a double sided foam tape would give you the ability to attach a plastic panel in which you can drill holes to bolt or screw the timer to the post.

3M Outdoor Mounting Tape is weather capable. I attached a sports logo to a motor vehicle for a friend with the stuff and it's been through a few years of car washes and remains attached.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ed's idea, you could get a plastic weatherproof junction box - or really any box that could be mounted and drilled through. Then drill some holes through the top and bottom for your connections and seal. This would keep the unit a little better isolated from the weather and you could paint the box, but it might look odd depending on where you place it.